# D3 chart is not clearing before redrawing

Tags: json, d3.js

I've setup a D3 arc to show a number (as percentage) and the chart itself works fine, but when i try and get it to update from the JSON feed (via PHP) it simply draws another item on the page without clearing.
Tried following any documentation online but nothing seems close to the code i'm seeing.

Latest attempt was to add ".data(meter).exit().remove();" but this made no difference.
The values being handed over from JSON are:
endPercent:0.13
asalabel:"00:00:05"

```
function doOnLoad() {
    var colors = {
    'pink': '#E1499A',
    'yellow': '#f0ff08',
    'green': '#47e495'
};
function initData(){
var color = colors.green;

var radius = 200;
var border = 40;
var padding = 30;
var startPercent = 0;
//var endPercent = 0.85;
var endPercent = [];
var valueLimit = 0.20;
var asalabel = [];


var twoPi = Math.PI * 2;
var formatPercent = d3.format('.0%');
var boxSize = (radius + padding) * 2;
var parent = d3.select('div#content');

getData = d3.json('getCallAsa.php', function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;
console.log(data);
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        value = JSON.parse(d.endPercent);
        value2 = d.value2;
        endPercent.push(value);
        asalabel.push(value2);

    });

var count = Math.abs((endPercent - startPercent) / 0.01);
var step = endPercent < startPercent ? -0.01 : 0.01;

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .innerRadius(radius)
    .outerRadius(radius - border);



var svg = parent.append('svg')
    .attr('width', boxSize)
    .attr('height', boxSize);

var defs = svg.append('defs');

var filter = defs.append('filter')
    .attr('id', 'blur');

filter.append('feGaussianBlur')
    .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic')
    .attr('stdDeviation', '7');


var g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize / 2 + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');


var meter = g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'progress-meter');

    // remove data not used
  g.datum(data).selectAll("path")
    .data(meter).exit().remove();

meter.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'background')
    .attr('fill', '#555')
    .attr('fill-opacity', 0.5)
    .attr('d', arc.endAngle(twoPi));

var foreground = meter.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'foreground')
    .attr("fill", function(d) { if (endPercent < valueLimit) { return colors.green;} else if (endPercent > valueLimit) { return colors.pink } else {return colors.yellow;};})
    .attr('fill-opacity', 1)
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { if (endPercent < valueLimit) { return colors.green;} else if (endPercent > valueLimit) { return colors.pink } else {return colors.yellow;};})
    .attr('stroke-width', 10)
    .attr('stroke-opacity', 1)
    .attr('filter', 'url(#blur)');

var front = meter.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'foreground')
    //.attr('fill', color)
    .attr('fill-opacity', 1)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { if (endPercent < valueLimit) { return colors.green;} else if (endPercent > valueLimit) { return colors.pink } else {return colors.yellow;};});

var numberText = meter.append('text')
    .attr("fill", function(d) { if (endPercent < valueLimit) { return colors.green;} else if (endPercent > valueLimit) { return colors.pink } else {return colors.yellow;};})
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dy', '.35em');

function updateProgress(progress) {
    meter.exit().remove();
    foreground.attr('d', arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
    front.attr('d', arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
    numberText.text(asalabel);
}

var progress = startPercent;


(function loops() {
    updateProgress(progress);

    if (count > 0) {
        count--;
        progress += step;
        setTimeout(loops, 10);
    }
})();

 });
}
setInterval(initData,2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move your svg initialization outside of your d3.json call, because you are currently creating a new svg per visualization, which is causing you to redraw the chart each time you load in new data. Then, I would clear the svg at the beginning of the d3.json call. Sample code below:

```
function doOnLoad() {
    var colors = {
        'pink': '#E1499A',
        'yellow': '#f0ff08',
        'green': '#47e495'
    };

    function initData() {
        var color = colors.green;
        var radius = 200;
        var border = 40;
        var padding = 30;
        var startPercent = 0;
        //var endPercent = 0.85;
        var endPercent = [];
        var valueLimit = 0.20;
        var asalabel = [];

        var twoPi = Math.PI * 2;
        var formatPercent = d3.format('.0%');
        var boxSize = (radius + padding) * 2;
        var parent = d3.select('div#content');

        // move this here
        var svg = parent.append('svg')
                .attr('width', boxSize)
                .attr('height', boxSize);

        getData = d3.json('getCallAsa.php', function(error, data) {
            if (error) throw error;

            // add this to clear your svg
            svg.selectAll("*").remove();

            data.forEach(function (d) {
                value = JSON.parse(d.endPercent);
                value2 = d.value2;
                endPercent.push(value);
                asalabel.push(value2);
            });

            var count = Math.abs((endPercent - startPercent) / 0.01);
            var step = endPercent < startPercent ? -0.01 : 0.01;

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .startAngle(0)
                .innerRadius(radius)
                .outerRadius(radius - border);

            var defs = svg.append('defs');

            var filter = defs.append('filter')
                .attr('id', 'blur');

            filter.append('feGaussianBlur')
                .attr('in', 'SourceGraphic')
                .attr('stdDeviation', '7');


            var g = svg.append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize / 2 + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');


            var meter = g.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'progress-meter');

            meter.append('path')
                .attr('class', 'background')
                .attr('fill', '#555')
                .attr('fill-opacity', 0.5)
                .attr('d', arc.endAngle(twoPi));

            var foreground = meter.append('path')
                .attr('class', 'foreground')
                .attr("fill", function(d) { if (endPercent < valueLimit) { return colors.green;} else if (endPercent > valueLimit) { return colors.pink } else {return colors.yellow;};})
                .attr('fill-opacity', 1)
                .attr("stroke", function(d) { if (endPercent < valueLimit) { return colors.green;} else if (endPercent > valueLimit) { return colors.pink } else {return colors.yellow;};})
                .attr('stroke-width', 10)
                .attr('stroke-opacity', 1)
                .attr('filter', 'url(#blur)');

            var front = meter.append('path')
                .attr('class', 'foreground')
                //.attr('fill', color)
                .attr('fill-opacity', 1)
                .attr("fill", function(d) { if (endPercent < valueLimit) { return colors.green;} else if (endPercent > valueLimit) { return colors.pink } else {return colors.yellow;};});

            var numberText = meter.append('text')
                .attr("fill", function(d) { if (endPercent < valueLimit) { return colors.green;} else if (endPercent > valueLimit) { return colors.pink } else {return colors.yellow;};})
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .attr('dy', '.35em');

            function updateProgress(progress) {
                meter.exit().remove();
                foreground.attr('d', arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
                front.attr('d', arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
                numberText.text(asalabel);
            }

            var progress = startPercent;


            (function loops() {
                updateProgress(progress);

                if (count > 0) {
                    count--;
                    progress += step;
                    setTimeout(loops, 10);
                }
            })();
        });
    }

    setInterval(initData,2000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but unfortunately this is still drawing new circles when it loads the new data.